# How would I make this code efficient?

Tags: javascript, json, each

First off, sorry for it not being so neat, I am still learning the ropes of javascript.

I am running this code in the google chrome console, but it takes too much time to run it, is there anything I am doing, that I can fix to make it run faster?

```
function snipebot(page, max_page, max_price){
 $.getJSON('http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?Subcategory=2&Keyword=&CurrencyType=0&pxMin=0&pxMax=0&SortType=2&SortAggregation=0&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&PageNumber=' + page, function(data){
  $.each(data, function(index, item){
   if (item['BestPrice'] <= max_price){
    $.get('http://www.roblox.com/Item.aspx?id=' + item['AssetId'], function(data){
     var purchaseData = $($(data).find(".PurchaseButton")[0]).data();
     if (purchaseData['expectedPrice'] <= item['BestPrice']){
      $.post('/API/Item.ashx?rqtype=purchase&productID=' + purchaseData['productId'] + '&expectedCurrency=1&expectedPrice=' + purchaseData['expectedPrice'] + '&expectedSellerId=' + purchaseData['expectedSellerId'] + '&userAssetID=' + purchaseData['userassetId'], function(){
       console.log('[' + item['BestPrice'] + ']' + item['Name'] + item['AssetId'] + '   user:' + purchaseData['seller-name'] + '   '  + '@' + new Date().toTimeString()) 
      });
     } else {
      console.log("Detected purchase:" + item['Name'] + item['AssetId'] + '    ' + purchaseData['seller-name']);
     }
    });
   };
  });
  setTimeout(function(){
    snipebot(page + 1 > max_page ? 1 : page + 1, max_page, max_price);
  });
 });
};
snipebot(1, 4, 50);
```

Comment: You are making many calls to external urls as far as i can see .. no way to control how much time that will take ... depends on the url in question ...

Comment: First, you need to define what efficient means to you.  Efficient can be fast on the local machine, fast load time, written in a way that it can be maintained easily, that it can be expanded efficiently ... each and probably other definitions might be able to be worked out together, but there will be areas where they cannot co-exist.

Comment: Efficient, for me would be the fastest I could make it.

Comment: Say a number of milliseconds or something like that, not just as fast as possible! -1

Comment: The only thing that's potentially slow here are the AJAX calls, and there's not much you can do to speed those up.

Comment: This is a potentially harmful software, i think the only reason for this post is to make somebody run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the worst case, a call to `snipebot()` makes 3 round trip to the backend. You should review your design and move some of your logic to the backend to reduce the round-trips.

1. `if (item['BestPrice'] <= max_price){ ...`
2. `if (purchaseData['expectedPrice'] <= item['BestPrice']){ ...`

Both conditions above can be tested at the backend and processed there.